# Getting buffer timeout error when making a POST request to the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am getting a timeout error when I try to make a POST request to the database:

```
MongooseError: Operation `sessions.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/don-alexantoine/Desktop/BCC-Website/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:20)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

This all started when I placed the routes into a different file. I don't what this why this is happening. I created API endpoints in the same manner and they work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

Router.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const Session = require('../models/sessions')
const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res)=>{

    res.render('home');
});

router.post('/',async (req, res)=>{

    try{
        const session = new Session({

            session_name: req.body.session_name,
            first_name: req.body.fname,
            last_name: req.body.lname,
            room: req.body.room,    
            max_capacity: req.body.max,
            session_time: req.body.time
        });

        console.log(session)
        const newsession = await session.save();

        console.log(newsession)

        res.redirect('/')
    }catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e)
    }
    
})

module.exports = router
```

Sessions.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    session_name:{
        type: String,
        required:[true, 'session name is required'],
        trim: true
    },

    first_name:{
        type: String,
        required:[true, 'Speaker last name is required']
    },

    last_name:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Speaker last name is required']
    },

    room:{
        required: [true, 'Room name is required'],
        type: String
    },

    max_capacity: {
        required: [true, 'Room max capacity is required'],
        type: Number,
        
    },

    session_time: {
        required: [true, 'Session time is required'],
        type: String
    },

    room_counts:[{

        count:{
            type: Number,
        },

        time:{
            type: String
        }
    }]
});

const Session = mongoose.model('session', SessionSchema);

module.exports = Session;
```

Main app file (app.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const path =  require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const sessionRouter = require('./routers/session');
const app = express();

const viewPath = path.join(__dirname, '../views');
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../views/partials');

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

app.use(sessionRouter);

app.set('views', viewPath);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
hbs.registerPartials(partialsPath);

app.listen(3000 || process.env.PORT, ()=>{

    console.log('server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Mongoose.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/bccDB', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify:true});
```

Comment: can you share more information with respect to your connection and how you are handling that across your project? @Alex Antoine

Comment: I made some edits. Basically, all of the requests are located in the router.js file. That file is using the mongoose model from sessions.js. Sessions.js contains the schema and the model for a session. If you have any more questions don't hesitate to ask. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After, looking into your code below are the mistakes that I have found out

- `const sessionRouter = require('./routers/session');` your need to change this to `const sessionRouter = require('./routers/Router');`
- secondly, your app is not connected to MongoDB. you have created the file but you have never called that file. I would recommend you to make a connect function, export it and call it inside the `app.js`

`Mongoose.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

function connectDB() {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/bccDB', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify:true});
}

module.exports = {
    connectDB
}
```

and initializing it inside `app.js`

```
const { connectDB } = require('./mongoose')

// create a connection to mongodb
connectDB()
```

Also, you need to handle the initialization in a better way in order to avoid crashing your application because of DB errors.

Comment: The initialization was the issue. I don't know why I followed to same steps from a tutorial and it worked. Thank you for your help